# Import images into the flash in the workspace in coordinates not equal to 0

Tags: flash

Why when importing images into a flash (ctrl+R), they are located in coordinates not equal to 0? They are constantly shifted, have to be checked and each time a group selection is located in coordinates 0.
Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: This question does not pose a programming problem. It is not related to **actionscript-3** either.

Comment: Not sure if that applies to your case but if you reimport the same images over and over again you don't have to delete them and reimport - you can overwrite the imported images outside of flash and then just update the images in flash from the same location. Then they should stay at the same coordinates. I don't remember from memory but I believe you have to right click on the image in the library and then there would be an "update" option